# Migrating content from production to development

Tags: 8, migrations, importing-exporting

I have a multilingual site built on the [Glazed Drupal CMS](https://www.drupal.org/project/cms) installation profile (Drupal 8).

It was upgraded to Drupal 9, but the upgrading process lasted around 3 months, and now new content from the production site (Drupal 8.9) needs to me be migrated to the new Drupal 9 site.

I can't just use the production site database - it was a lot of changes when switching from Glazed CMS to DXPR and these changes are in the database also. (Glazed builder was updated to [DXPR Builder](https://www.drupal.org/project/dxpr_builder) and Glazed theme to [DXPR theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/dxpr_theme) (v1)).

How do I migrate the latest updates on production (where Drupal 8 is used) to a development server (where Drupal 9 is used)? Content types include the *Drag-n-Drop* content type (Glazed Builder content).

I know this question could be a little specific, but maybe there is a solution that could be universal. There are a few modules I considered.

1. [Default content](https://www.drupal.org/project/default_content)
2. [Entity share](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_share)
3. [Content export CSV](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_export_csv)
4. [Views data export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export)

I don't have experience with all these modules, so I'm looking for someone who used to migrate content from Drupal 8 to Drupal 9.

Comment: Is a custom service / class based importer feasible? That's what I normally do.  We don't use page builders though.

Comment: could you please share some examples if this is possible?